# what is the most efficient way of making multiple APIs calls in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

what is the most efficient way of making multiple APIs calls in ReactJS?

I have one API (say API 1) which give me DataID.
passing this DataID I need to call another API (say API 2) which will give me list of vehiclesId. like calling Get ../api/{DataID}/vehicles/  gives below

```
                       {
                        "vehicleIds": [
                                        603285889,
                                        1328361472,
                                        1333092761,
                                        1595876995,
                                        799206723
                                      ]
                       }
```

By Passing  DataID and VehicleID to another API (say API 3) I will get Vehicle details along with DealerId.  Like calling Get ../api/{DataId}/vehicles/{VehicleId} gives below

```
       {
            "vehicleId": 2063928446,
            "year": 2004,
            "make": "MINI",
            "model": "Cooper",
            "dealerId": 1508315732
        }
```

Now passing DataId and DealerId to another API (say API 4)  I will get Dealer Name .
Like calling Get ../api/{DataId}/dealers/{DealerId} gives below

```
{
"dealerId": 1508315732,
"name": "Bob's Cars"
}
```

Now what is the most efficient ways to make multiple API calls to retrieves all vehicles and dealers for that DataID ?
Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: Use promise for this type of thing i.e. call your API by whatever method you prefer (fetch or Axios) and use `then` after that

Answer (score 0):

You could store intermediates ids using `useState`, with an init value of `null`, then use something like

```
const [dataId, setDataId] = useState<number>(null);

// this effect will be triggered on component mount
useEffect(() => {
  // launch request to get dataId, then store it into the component state
  fetch(...).then(setDataId);
}, []); // notice the empty dependencies array

// each time dataId changes, this effect will be triggered
useEffect(() => {
  if(!!dataId) {
    fetch(...).then(...); // request using dataId value to get other values
  }
}, [dataId]);
```

But this could grow in size and become hard to maintain I guess. I would suggest to consider 3rd party libraries like the awesome react-query to handle your server state. To perform dependent queries with react-query : https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/dependent-queries

Comment: can you please provide some code considering the details ?

Comment: I updated my pseudo code to make it a little more accurate